# JpaRepository Not supported for DML operations [delete query]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have written a query to delete some objects in my interface extending `JPaRepository`, but when I execute the query it throws an exception!
Can anyone explain it for me?

Query:

```java
public interface LimitRepository extends JpaRepository<CLimit, Long> {

    @Query("delete from CLimit l where l.trader.id =:#{#trader.id}")
    void deleteLimitsByTrader(@Param("trader") CTrader trader);
}
```

I got this error, can anyone Please, explain this for me, and thank you all :)

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from com.query.domain.CLimit l where l.trader.id =:__$synthetic$__1]
  at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.errorIfDML(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:318)
  at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:369)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
  at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.deleteLimitsByTrader(Unknown Source)
  at com.query.service.impl.LimitServiceImpl.deleteLimitsByTrader(LimitServiceImpl.java:138)
  at com.query.controller.UserController.deleteUser(UserController.java:96)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:893)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:656)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: My problem was a `delete method` with `List` return type. :)

Comment: I had 2 problems: 1. Method was returning non-void. 2. I didn't add @Modifying

Comment: Note: return type can be Integer/int, not only void

Comment: @standalone what value should we expect in the Integer return type.

Comment: @SameedTariq the number of affected rows(like in SQL delete/update queries)

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface LimitRepository extends JpaRepository<CLimit, Long> {
  @Modifying
  @Query("delete from CLimit l where l.trader.id =:#{#trader.id}")
  void deleteLimitsByTrader(@Param("trader") CTrader trader);
}
```

Whenever you are trying to modify a record in db, you have to mark it as `@Modifying`, which instruct Spring that it can modify existing records.

The modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type, otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: Just a simple point, the method has to be void! I had this problem 'cause in our project we were expecting an integer and so we had the same issue, even with the annotations. It took us a bit to realize so it could be helpful for someone else ;)

Comment: @Afridi may i return int instead of void. So i can track how much rows deleted.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Yes, you can return int/Integer (or void as mentioned).

Comment: This works, but check out also @tk's answer. The `@Transactional` annotation should be placed elsewhere, if that is possible.

Comment: Return type can be also `Integer/int`, not only void. Value is representing the number of affected rows.

Comment: @Transactional is not needed here

Comment: @Transactional might be obsolete

Comment: @ValerijDobler I needed Transactional too :(

Comment: @Tupac The transaction shouldn't be opened at repository level, but rather at the service- or better yet at controller-layer.

Answer (score 60):

I had the same issue and I tried @afridi's answer which is working fine but bad practice, as far as I understand. you should not use `@Transactional` annotation in the repository class but service(and implementation) classes. please find the below answer.

> LimitServiceImpl.java

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
...
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteLimitsByTrader(CTrader trader) {
// here im calling the LimitRepository interface. 
 getEntityRepository().deleteLimitsByTrader(trader);
}
```

> LimitRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
...
public interface LimitRepository extends JpaRepository<CLimit, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Query("delete from CLimit l where l.trader.id =:#{#trader.id}")
  void deleteLimitsByTrader(@Param("trader") CTrader trader);

}
```

make sure to use the correct imports.

Comment: My Observation -`@Modifying` should be put on repository method instead of service. Learning.

Comment: Why put "Transactional" in service? The transaction is needed due to the repository. If you put "Transactional" in the service, and some operations are needed before / after the repository call, you'll (keep) open a transaction (and then resources) even though is not required.

Comment: If @Transactional is not added the following exception is throw. javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to add two `annotations` above of method .

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
```

Comment: this is the better solution I think

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by using `EntityManager.createQuery("your deleteStatement").executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Transactional(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)`
and `@Modifying(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying)`
which solved similar issue for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using repositary,then most of the answers work.
If anyone is using entity manager

then use
1.Transactional
2.entitymanager.createQuery("your deleteStatement").executeUpdate();

```
@Transactional
public Integer somemethod() {

entitymanager.createQuery("your deleteStatement").executeUpdate();

}
```