# spring QueryExecutionRequestException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

using spring jpa.

the repository:

```
public interface FacultyMemberImpl extends JpaRepository<FacultyMember,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM FacultyMember e WHERE e.name =:name")
    List<FacultyMember> getFacultyByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE FacultyMember e SET e.name=:name, e.department=:department WHERE e.id=:id")
    List<FacultyMember> updateFaculty(@Param("id") int id,@Param("name") String name,@Param("department") String department);
}
```

the error

```
2019-01-28 09:57:53.027 ERROR 14264 --- [nio-8181-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.facultyProject.faculty_project.dao.FacultyMember e SET e.name=:name, e.department=:department WHERE e.id=:id]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.facultyProject.faculty_project.dao.FacultyMember e SET e.name=:name, e.department=:department WHERE e.id=:id]] with root cause
```

Comment: Can you add importations? the first impression, you were trying to modifying a record in database which you have to mark it as @Transactional as well as Modifying, in order to say Spring that it can modify existing records. but with updating that you did, looks like your importations are wrong

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022076/jparepository-not-supported-for-dml-operations-delete-query the method should return void otherwise the exception keeps getting thrown. You could try that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JpaRepository Not supported for DML operations \[delete query\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022076/jparepository-not-supported-for-dml-operations-delete-query)