# JpaRepository Not supported for DML operations (Delete)

Tags: java, jpa, testing, junit, dml

I keep trying to create a user and delete it afterwards as a part of my tests, but I keep getting the same error *org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operation*s even after continuously changing the code in both my Repository and Controller.

**This is the code in my Repository:**

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteById(long id) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "delete from UserModel as u where u.id=:id"
        ).setParameter("id", id);
        query.getSingleResult();
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

**This is the code in my Controller:**

```
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteUser")
    public @ResponseBody
    void deleteUser(@RequestParam long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        ResponseEntity.ok(null);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JpaRepository Not supported for DML operations \[delete query\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022076/jparepository-not-supported-for-dml-operations-delete-query)

Comment: Sadly no, that is a whole different approach than mine

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception is triggering due to the `query.getSingleResult();` line which is trying to fetch a result from a DELETE query (which is an UPDATE type of query).

Try changing the code like this:

```
@Override
public void deleteById(long id) {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "delete from UserModel as u where u.id=:id"
    ).setParameter("id", id);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I get a different error message when trying that, it then changes into a EmptyResultDataAccesException with the commentary that there is no entity found for query

Comment: I suspect the entity being deleted does not exist in the database. Try inserting a row manually into the database , copy its ID and then test this code by feeding said ID value into the method.

Comment: I have tried the query in MySQL and it does work so I don't think the query is the problem